# How can I make css compile in .vue files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vuejs2, webpacker

I'm using [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) gem for a rails development when I use scss or sass the compiler works on **.vue** files but does not work for plain css.

This works:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
form label{
  color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

But this doesn't

```
<style scoped>
form label{
  color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

The part of the config for sass in webpack

```
module.exports = {
  test: /.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    extractCSS: true,
    loaders: {
      js: 'babel-loader',
      file: 'file-loader',
      scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
      sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran across this in the past. Since css is a subset of scss, is there a strong reason to spend time trying to fix this?

Comment: Just an idea: If you add `css: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader` in the loaders object doesn't work?

Comment: @Phil The main reason to fix this is that there are many **vue** node modules use only css

Answer (score 0):

This is really strange but it just worked, change the line in `config/webpack/loaders/sass.js`

> { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: env.NODE_ENV === 'production' } },

with

> 'css-loader',

and run `./bin/webpack-dev-server` and it was works it can compile css, then I switched back the changes to the original and it was working.

> { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: env.NODE_ENV === 'production' } },

I don't understand what happened but it worked and I had tried many things.